# Column Design multiple screen

Tags: app-inventor

Overview: I am creating a game app with 6 different screens. I want to create 2 columns and 3 rows with app inventor to implement this.

This is what I tried

Screen1: AlighHorizontal - left
Block1: AlignHorizontal -left, AlignVertical - top
Block2: AlignHorizontal -left, AlignVertical - top

This places 2 blocks. 1 on the top left and 1 underneath it. The result I wanted was 1 block to the left and 1 block beside it.

Edit* 6 columns -> 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

I am just being overall extremely ignorant it's pretty simple all you have to do is put objects inside the horrizontalArrangement and it will arrange itself horrizontaly.